# Build Maven -SNAPSHOT project in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, snapshot

I believe that the answer will be really easy, but I haven't figure out how to do it.

**The problem is:**

I have a third-party project, which is being cloned from github, so I'm not going to change anything there, but I need this project for my work with MUnit.

The project is mule-interceptor-module and it has a version 3.4-M4-SNAPSHOT.

I created a build in Jenkins and I want to get ***mule-interceptor-module-3.4-M4-SNAPSHOT.jar*** after it, but **Jenkins REMOVES -SNAPSHOT from the jar name and updates pom.xml with new version: 3.4-M4 instead of 3.4-M4-SNAPSHOT**. The project, which uses this one (munit) in its dependencies has 3.4-M4-SNAPSHOT. So I need the SNAPSHOT in version.

**What I tried to do:**

I tried to build the same project on the server, which my Jenkins is installed on, using just mvn clean install and I got mule-interceptor-module-3.4-M4-SNAPSHOT.jar.

**The question is:**

*How to tune Jenkins so that I could finally have SNAPSHOT build?*

**My job setup:**

- JDK: jdk 1.6.0_45
- Source Code Management:

  - Git
  - Repository URL: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-interceptor-module.git
  - Branch Specifier (blank for default):3.4.x
  - Repository browser: githubweb
  - URL: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-interceptor-module/
- Pre Steps:

  - Execute shell: git checkout 3.4.x
- Build:

  - Root POM: pom.xml
  - Goals and options: clean install
- Post steps:

  - Run regardless of build result
- Build Settings: 
      - Publish Checkstyle analysis results
      - Publish FindBugs analysis results

[Jenkins Console output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6nrjmqkckttaj5/Jenkins%20Console%20Output.txt)
[Jenkins Console output wirh -X](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7k6oikmtmfjexh0/Jenkins%20Console%20Output%20-X.txt)

**The solution:**

1. in Jenkins /Configuration/Build/Advanced check in Use private Maven repository
2. Choose Strategy: Local to the workspace
3. remove everything from /workspace folder by `rm -R *`

@Grove: thanks you a lot for the support!

Comment: Can you share your Jenkins job setup? I don't think Jenkins would willingly rename generated artefacts, I suspect it might be Maven related.

Comment: Grove, I posted the update, where you can find the configuration.

Comment: Grove, I do believe it's maven related issue, but I can't figure out how to get the behavior I want to.

Comment: Do you have configured any release parameters? Also any chance you can attach the log?

Comment: Looking at that [pom](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-interceptor-module/blob/3.4.x/pom.xml), it looks like it should use `3.4-M4-SNAPSHOT` as a suffix.  Where is that 0 coming from?  The only thing that says `3.4.0` is the dependency you're using.  Are you sure you're looking at the right place?  Maybe you're confusing the target output for a dependency it's using?  What's the *full* file name of the jar jenkins is using?

Comment: tieTYT, sorry, it was a mistyping.

Comment: @tieTYT, the full name is mule-interceptor-module-3.4-M4.jar

Comment: @Grove, I didn't configure any release parameters.

Comment: Then add a -X to the Maven goals and options, run it and attach the logs, because if you didn't modify the pom in your clone repo, this should work as a charm.

Comment: @Grove, I added the log. Please, tell me if you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

I can see in the logs: `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/3.4.x' by 1 commit.` and `Building Mule Interceptor Module 3.4-M4`. Could it be that your revision has 3.4-M4 as a version in the pom?

Comment: it's ahead because Jenkins (or Maven in it) changed the pom.xml when it removed -SNAPSHOT from <version>3.4-M4-SNAPSHOT</version>. `-bash-4.1$ ll
total 52
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins   241 Oct 28 17:05 LICENSE_HEADER.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 27623 Oct 28 17:05 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  6296 Nov  1 14:34 pom.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins   320 Oct 28 17:05 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 4 jenkins jenkins  4096 Oct 28 17:05 src
drwxr-xr-x 9 jenkins jenkins  4096 Nov  1 14:35 target
-bash-4.1$`

Comment: You can see the source here: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-interceptor-module/blob/3.4.x/pom.xml

Comment: I think you need to revert the change in your local repo, otherwise it will keep using it

Comment: I do it every time and jenkins changes it. What I need to understand how to make Jenkins not to change it.

Comment: Let's revert one more time and commit (or completely remove the clone), add a -X so the maven config reads `clean compile -X`, build and check the new log which should contain the full set of debug information, because your previous -x log still has the 3.4-M4 version

Comment: thank you a lot! With your help I fixed the build. Now it really works as charm! Anyway, I'm going to use this approach for the munit build and prove it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help, happy coding :) Also you can post your own solution and chose it as the correct answer, if none of the others  did the job

Comment: I'm still having troubles...now the SNAPSHOT in jar name is being substituted with timestamp, which I don't need...Where can I switch is off?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40400/discussion-between-grove-and-laura)

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

- in Jenkins /Configuration/Build/Advanced check in Use private Maven repository
- Choose Strategy: Local to the workspace
- remove everything from /workspace folder by rm -R *

Answer (score 1):

Why are using SNAPSHOT dependency from a 3rd party ? The standard is to use a RELEASE version, right ?

**Answer** Anyways the fact that using the private maven repository worked for you proves just one thing, that the [negative cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_cache) in your server's maven repo was causing the problem. See this [Q and A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513758/maven-release-plugin-snapshot-project-needed/13582861#13582861) from me more than a year back, when exactly the same solution worked for me, albiet for a different problem and I marked it as the answer. Only to find a few months later that I did not go to the root cause of the problem and just found a workaorund.

To test this theory, set `<updatepolicy> true <updatepolicy>` and `use maven -U clean install`. It will have the same effect as your solution of using a private repo.

Comment: I'm using a SNAPSHOT, because the 3d party don't have a release, but they are going to have it and I like the testing framework.