# How do I cure "Can't release project due to non released dependencies" when releasing a child module?

Tags: maven, dependencies, snapshot, release-management, maven-release-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.1.1 and trying to use the Maven release plugin to release a child module of a multi-module project.  The parent module was released and this child module is not in the parent's child module list.  In my child module pom.xml file, I have

```
    <parent>
            <artifactId>subco</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.mainco.subco</groupId>
            <version>52.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <name>myproject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.mainco.subco</groupId>
                            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
   </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
            ...
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mainco.subco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

However, when I run the below

```
mvn -B -DdevelopmentVersion=52.0.1-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=52.0.0 -Dusername=***** -Dtag=myproject-52.0.0 -DskipTests -P prod -Dresume=false -DdryRun=true -DallowTimestampedSnapshots=true org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.2:prepare
```

I get the errors

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.2:prepare (default-cli) on project myproject: Can't release project due to non released dependencies :
[ERROR] org.mainco.subco:core:jar:52.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
...
[ERROR] org.mainco.subco:subco:pom:52.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I'm not able to change any properties in the parent pom.xml file … is there anything I can do in the child module to get the above command to run successfully?  I like using "${project.version}" because I don't have to hard-code versions in my pom.  Also note that I'm using "-DallowTimestampedSnapshots=true" which is getting ignored.

**Edit:**

Even adding a separate version element to the pom, like so

```
    <parent>
            <artifactId>subco</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.mainco.subco</groupId>
            <version>52.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <name>myproject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <version>52.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

results in the same errors as above.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the release plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the child modules I depended on were the same version as the parent, I changed

```
${project.version}
```

to

```
${project.parent.version}
```

and using the version configuration in the edit, the errors went away.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming from googling the error:
Check if you have any dependency in your `pom.xml` that contains the word `SNAPSHOT`.
Or if your project's version has a `SNAPSHOT` and one or more of your dependencies use the project version:

```
<version>${project.version}</version>
```

**Reason** ist that maven simply does not allow SNAPSHOT dependencies in mvn release:prepare.

You can also use the option `-DignoreSnapshots=true` but **use it with caution** and only if you know what you are doing, otherwise you end up releasing SNAPSHOT dependencies!!

After setting `-DignoreSnapshots=true`, `mvn release:prepare` was fine with them and I can see in Log:

```
17:34:54 [INFO] Ignoring SNAPSHOT depenedencies and plugins ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the released version of the parent.

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>subco</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.mainco.subco</groupId>
    <version>52.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

You'll also need to specify the version of the current project; since it isn't released with the parent, it needs to have its own version element.

Comment: That doesn't work.  Doing that results in the error "You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list" -- I was told you can't release "releases", as it were -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054185/you-dont-have-a-snapshot-project-in-the-reactor-projects-list-when-using-jen

Comment: Note, see my edit, but adding your suggestion (please make sure what I posted above is what you intended), results in the same errors -- "Can't release project due to non released dependencies".