# Deploy Java Spring Boot Jar to Maven central

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, sonatype

I have developped a jar library used in multi-module Java Spring Boot projects but I want now I would like to upload it to Maven central repository.

To do that I created a new project containing only my library that I adapted to make it buildable and then published it into a Github repository.

I have then followed this post to deploy it [How to publish JAR to Maven central](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846802/how-to-manually-publish-jar-to-maven-central) to Maven but didn't succeed as I have a `401 Forbidden` error when using `mvn clean deploy`.

Here is the full error thrown by IntelliJ :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.7:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) on project okta-connector: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact io.github.lyvoc:okta-connector:jar.asc:javadoc:1.0-20210427.100037-1 from/to ossrh (https://oss.sonatype.org/cont
ent/repositories/snapshots): Transfer failed for https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/github/my_user/project-connector/1.0-SNAPSHOT/project-connector-1.0-20210427.100037-1-javadoc.jar.asc 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Here is my *pom.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>9</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>io.github.my_user</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-connector</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project-connector</name>
    <description>Project API connector</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-boot-starter-version>2.4.4</spring-boot-starter-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-starter-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-starter-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                    <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My *.m2/settings.xml* :

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  <offline>false</offline>
    <servers>
    <server>
      <id>ossrh</id>
      <username>sonatype_username</username>
      <password>my_password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>ossrh</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <gpg.executable>gpg</gpg.executable>
        <gpg.passphrase>my_password</gpg.passphrase>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

I used *gpg* and not *gpg2* for the public key as I had this one installed.

I can't find where the issue comes from as the similar cases I have found are simply using the wrong password or forgot to put `-SNAPSHOT` for artifact version.

Thank you for any help !

Comment: First read this: https://central.sonatype.org/ second use different id's for snapshot/release repo

Comment: I already watched this. I don't see what's wrong with my setttings then, I'm using the right Id here