# Is SNAPSHOT or non-SNAPSHOT the convention for libraries and Maven when doing a release for others to use?

Tags: maven, maven-reactor

I'm excluding this from the *trunk vs branch release* question because that's a separate issue.

Assuming you have finished your development iteration, and are pushing out a release for other people to use in their projects.

Now some members of my team say:

> SNAPSHOT is for iterating in your team - and non-SNAPSHOTs are for actual releases.

But when I look at the reactor plugin and associated commentary - it appears to [say the opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20056439/15441):

> You're only supposed to release SNAPSHOT versions. That means your version number would be like 3.0.3-SNAPSHOT.

My question is: **Is SNAPSHOT or non-SNAPSHOT the convention for libraries and Maven when doing a release for others to use?**

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554688/maven-versioning-best-practices/9554758#9554758

Comment: The text "release SNAPSHOT versions" means you produce a release version by removinf the SNAPSHOT tag. This will then install into the release repositoy (where unlike SNAPSHOTs nothig is ever overwritten).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Maven: The Complete Reference, 3.3.1. Project Versions](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html#pom-reationships-sect-versions):

> SNAPSHOT Versions
>
> Maven versions can contain a string literal to signify that a project is **currently under active development**. If a version contains the string “-SNAPSHOT,” then Maven will expand this token [...] when you install or **release this component**.
>
> ...
>
> Why would you use this? SNAPSHOT versions are used for projects **under active development**. [...], if the next release of your system is going to have a version "1.4", your project would have a version "1.4-SNAPSHOT" until it was **formally released**.
>
> ...
>
> When releasing a project, you should resolve all dependencies on SNAPSHOT versions to dependencies on **released versions**. If a project depends on a SNAPSHOT, it is not stable as the dependencies may change over time. [...] SNAPSHOT versions are for development only.

[Emphasizes by me.]

This means for me:

From a technical POV one can release any version, snapshot or not. But a (technically) released snapshot version is not a (formally) *released version* from a semantical POV.

Answer (score 0):

`SNAPSHOT` is assigned when development is under progress, after completion of development we need to release, then your version will not include `SNAPSHOT`. You can cross verify this in Internet. No jar which we use for general purpose contains `SNAPSHOT`. At the end they all are GA (General Available) releases.

Example: [spring-data-mongodb-1.9.2.RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb-parent). So what your team members told is true.